# Why doesn't the sample proportion give a realistic $z$ score value?

Tags: statistics

> $13$% of people took a math course. What is the probability that in a $350$ randomly selected sample, less than $40$ people take the course?

So I have $X\sim Bin(350, \frac{13}{100})$

Then let $Y \sim N(\frac{13}{100}, \sqrt{0.00032314}^2)$

I want $P(X<40) = P(\hat{p}<\frac{4}{10})$

Then $P(z<\frac{\frac{4}{10}-\frac{13}{100}}{\sqrt{0.00032314}^2})$
which is obviously very wrong.

Where did it go wrong, and why did it go wrong?

Comment: What is $Y$? Why is $0.00032314$ relevant?

Comment: $Y$ approximates the normal distribution, hence $Y \sim N(...)$. $ 0.00032314$ is the variance that thus is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $X$ of people taking the course is $B(n,\,p)$-distributed with $n=350,\,p=0.13$. Its variance is $npq,\,q:=1-p$. The $z$-score of $X$ is $Z:=\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{npq}}$, so the Normal approximation of $P(X<40)$ is$$P\left(Z<\frac{40-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\right)=P\left(Z<\frac{40-350\times0.13}{\sqrt{350\times0.13\times0.87}}\right).$$(Depending on how you seek to discretize the Normal variable approximating $X$, you might replace $40$ with e.g. $39.5$.)

Comment: From your answer, I see that my Variance was incorrect.

Comment: Hmmm, so this is a normal approximation question. But I thought it was a sample proportion also. How is it not? You "survey" $350$ people and are given the "pass" rate $\frac{13}{100}$

Comment: @user71207 You could also approximate the proportion as Normal, but it boils down to the same calculation concerning $z$-scores.

Comment: Yeah, ok so that's what I was trying to do. My question was "where did I go wrong" if both ways *should* work?

Comment: @user71207 Well for starters, $40/350\ne4/10$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, solved. Sorry, I don't have a clue why I decided to divide $40$ by $100$. yes, it should indeed be $\frac{40}{350}$ not $\frac{40}{100}$.

Comment: A further question: "You could also approximate the proportion as Normal, but it boils down to the same calculation concerning -scores." If I am calculating the "proportion" as the normal, then what are you taking it to be?

Comment: @user71207 The proportion is $X/350$. Its $z$-score is the same as for $X$, which is what I worked with. More generally, if $a>0$ then $X$ has the same $z$-score as does $aX+b$ (if $a<0$, the $z$-scores differ by a sign).